# New Relic Alert is not triggering alerts for the first event

Tags: sidekiq, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have a alert condition configured as below, but even after meeting the condition alert notification is not triggering for the first time, after 2 or 3 events its triggering. Can somebody please help me, what am i missing here?.

alert condition:

```
NRQL> SELECT count(newrelic.timeslice.value) AS `Custom/Sidekiq/DeadQueue` FROM Metric WHERE metricTimesliceName = 'Custom/Sidekiq/DeadQueue' AND `entity.guid` = 'xyz'

 Metric query result is > 0.0 at least once in 1 min
```

As the query returns 1 for the first event.

Comment: It may be the frequency of that data point coming into NR, so you may have to tune the condition's aggregation settings. Check out these docs:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts-applied-intelligence/new-relic-alerts/advanced-alerts/understand-technical-concepts/streaming-alerts-key-terms-concepts/

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-how-can-i-figure-out-which-aggregation-method-to-use/164288

Comment: Yea i have changed my aggregation settings from default to event timer, its working now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert condition aggregation settings needed to be tuned according to the frequency of data ingested:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts-applied-intelligence/new-relic-alerts/advanced-alerts/understand-technical-concepts/streaming-alerts-key-terms-concepts/

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-how-can-i-figure-out-which-aggregation-method-to-use/164288